# How can I make my Select Box Match the size of other text elements in Bootstrap 2.1.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make my Select Box have the same size as the Text Boxes Above.

See in [BootPly](http://www.bootply.com/i7R37AQkld)

You can find that the select box is smaller than the other two input fields. I want them to have exactly the same size.

I am using Bootstrap 2.1.1.

Comment: if you have a chance to upgrade to bootstrap 3+ then use class `form-control` for `input[text,password,number,tel,date] , select , textarea`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give `box-sizing:border-box` css property to your select box:

```
.form-signin-signup select {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

With cross browser support:

```
.form-signin-signup select {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Check this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Ny9vaCGfw4)

[MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

[Some CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Comment: But this option reduces the size of all text boxes + the select box itself. I want the size to remain the same.

Comment: @user3142215 you can increase the width and height of input  accordingly